# Unset where on query

Tags: magento-1.8, query, extend

How do you unset a where on a query. I have extended a core function and it has the following code:

```
$select->where('is_active = ?', 1)
```

In my extended function I want to remove this where condition. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the full `where` like this `$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)` but not just a part from it.

But you can do a sneaky think and add an other condition that cancels the first one.

```
$select->orWhere('is_active <> ?', 1);
```